# Marshmallow How to Enforce a Required Field when Dumping?

Tags: python, marshmallow

```
>>> class Foo(Schema):
...     id = fields.Int(dump_only=True, required=True)
...     name = fields.Str(required=True)
...
>>>
>>> Foo().dump({'asdf': 'abc'})
{}
```

I would have thought that this would raise a ValidationError.

Is there anyway to get a Marshmallow schema to enforce the required fields when calling `dump` ?

Answer (score 0):

Marshmallow only validates on load. It is a design choice.

You can use a `pre_load` method for this.

I just realized this could also be achieved with a default callable raising a `ValidationError`.

Untested code:

```py
class Foo(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True, required=True, default=lambda: raise ValidationError("missing id field")
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use `.load({})` instead of `.dump()`

purpose of `.dump()` is to jsonify an object/ instance. if the instance doesn't have `name` field then it will not throw an error because it's not dump's job to validate.

And technically, you need to validate data before adding to database or create objects, not while jsonifying your models.

In case you just want to user Marshmallow for just validating json body, you may use `.load()`

```py
>>> Foo().load({})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/coder/Projects/my-project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 722, in load
    return self._do_load(
  File "/home/coder/Projects/my-project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 909, in _do_load
    raise exc
marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'name': ['Missing data for required field.']}
```